# Border Radius and Browser Zoom

Tags: html, css, sass, border-radius

Trying to figure out a very strange issue with css border-radius in relation to the browser zoom. As you can see in the gif below, the border radius changes whenever the position of element changes.

The weird part is that it only happens when I am zoomed to 125%. I am using Chrome on a MacBook if that helps at all. Here is a simple [CodePen](https://codepen.io/erisman20/pen/MWvwxYJ) that replicates the issue for me.

```html
<span></span>

<style>
span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Example Gif]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are zoomed to 125% and Chrome is having issues with what's called "fractional pixels". This article covers the topic in-depth: https://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/browsers-and-fractional-pixels/ but a great callout is:

> In this case Firefox and IE8 round the div width to the nearest whole
> pixel, all the other tested browsers use the integer value only.

On a 1x monitor (where each pixel directly correlates to a single RGB lightsource) a browser can either display the pixel as a part of the blue circle "ON" or not a part of the blue circle "OFF". It looks like you're showing a 1x monitor demonstration in the video.

When a fractional pixel is < 0.5 it is "OFF" in a 1x scenario, and "ON" > 0.5. 2x Monitors can show greater density, and so this scenario is less common with them.

The issue will never go away, you will continue to see this behaviour when zoomed in or out in your browser. The rendering is atypical and skewed because you the user have chosen to view it that way, but for any other user using normal zoom - it will show as expected.

Comment: An interesting article but old. Do you know of one which discusses modern screens (where 1 CSS pixel can map to several screen pixel) in some depth? One can get sort of rounding error there too - with screen pixels sometimes 'left behind' when a part pixel is to be shown.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for that! Makes my custom radio buttons tough since they look terrible on some zoom levels